# sqlite3 loading xml as datatype text

Tags: xml, sqlite

I'm trying to insert the table which has two coloumns "CommandType" (varchar), "Definition" (text)... my definition coloumn's (text) xml is in the following pattern,

```
<err_handler>
  <err_group number="1">
    <!--1-Database, 2-system,-->
    <err_detail search_str="SQL Server does not exist or access denied">
      <number>101</number>
      <level>1</level>
```

When I run the sql insert query, it fails at err_group number = "1" .. How can I avoid this error? syntax error..?

Comment: I thought SQLite had a [dynamic type system](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), where you could put pretty much any content into any column.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Instead of double quotes, I've used single quotes and it worked..

Comment: SQLite supports arbitrary binary data and yes, has a dynamic type system! Your problem is shell command syntax. Using, eg, [C/C++ API](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html) you can use `sqlite3_bind_blob` to safely add ANY data to your database.